# How to prevent array from adding (sum) together

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have an array.  My program goes through and sets up the array.  However, when I display the array,it's adding the arrays together.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class frmMain
Dim connetionString As String 
Dim connection As SqlConnection 
Dim command As SqlCommand 
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter 
Dim ds As New DataSet 
Dim sql As String 
Dim yPoint As Integer
Dim LocationDB As String
Dim dtstartdate As Date
Dim dtenddate As Date
Dim LocationName As String
Dim BookSales(17) As Integer 
Public Shared locationcounter As Integer

Dim i As Integer





Public Sub Get_Info()



    If locationcounter < 18 Then

        dtstartdate = dtpStartDate.Value
        dtenddate = dtpEndDate.Value.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)


        Try
            connetionString = "Data Source=" & LocationDB & ";Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=test"
            sql = "Select * from fGetdata"
            connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
            connection.Open()
            command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 130
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", dtstartdate)
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", dtenddate)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            connection.Close()
            connection.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)


        End Try
        For Each FoundRow As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            Select Case FoundRow("CategoryName")
                Case "TOTAL"
                    Select Case FoundRow("Description")
                        Case "BOOK", "BOOK SALES", "GC"
                            BookSales(i) = BookSales(i) + (FoundRow("netAmt"))
                    End Select

            End Select

        Next
        MsgBox(LocationName & BookSales(i))
        MsgBox(LocationName & BookSales(0))
        MsgBox(LocationName & BookSales(1))


    End If


End Sub

Public Sub GetLocation()
        Select Case locationcounter
            Case "1"
                LocationName = "Location1"
                Locationdb = "10.0.1.52"
            Case "2"
                LocationName = "Location2"
                Locationdb = "10.0.1.51"
            Case "3"
                LocationName = "Location3"
                Locationdb = "10.0.1.50"

        End Select
    End Sub
```

Button Click:

```
For x = 1 To 3

            GetLocation()
            Label1.Text = LocationName
            Label1.Refresh()
            Get_Info()
            i = i + 1
            locationcounter = locationcounter + 1
        Next
```

I am getting:

```
Location1 5
Location2 25
Location3 35
```

I would like to get:

```
Location1 5
Location2 20
Location3 10
```

For some reason the arrays are adding together

Comment: Where do you increment `i`? Since you don't, you use e.g. BookSales(0) for every row, thus adding value after value to it.

Comment: It's in my button Loop.  I'll add that.

Comment: This runs a stored procedure as well as part of "Get_Info" but i figured that wasn't too important here, since the problem is the array.

Comment: I added code to send a message box of "BookSales(0)" and "BookSales(1)"  BookSales(0) displays correctly, (1) displays the sum

Comment: Where do you declare *i* ?

Comment: I declare it as "Integer" under Public Class frmMain

Comment: Why is BookSales declared inside the Get_Info method?  Is the result to load an array with the results from the GetLocation method?

Comment: Post *GetLocation()* sub. The issue is there, propably

Comment: I updated to show the entire sub.

Comment: Where is *GetLocation()* and *Get_Info()*?

Comment: See Update.  You'll see Get location and Get_info

Comment: Shouldn't the sql statement include the parameters so you filter the data correctly?  Maybe you are picking up extra data and it coincidentally added up to the location values.

Comment: I really feel like the issue is in booksales(i) = Booksales(i) +.....

Comment: No, I checked all the way through.  It's definitely adding.  I'm going to end up filtering this in 10 separate case statements.  This means I'd have to write 10 sql queries for 17 sites... I'd rather do it progrmatically instead of at the SQL level

Comment: @Gridly, Your comment jarred something loose.  I'm not clearing the Dataset!  This means, it's searching the case statements, and doing what it's supposed to do.  Just adding each query to the dataset!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the problem is that the DataSet was getting reused so it accumulated the results on each loop.

You need to clean up the coding style.  Put things in as tight of scope as possible.  In this case all the vars used by the Get_Info() method should be declared within the method.  This prevents side effects from long living variables.  The DataSet is only used in the Get_Info method so it should only exist there.

Clean up the resources in a Finally block.  In the example below I moved the connection.Dispose into the finally block.  You only need to call Dispose, you don't need the Close also.

You should also enable Option Strict and Option Explicit.  These will help prevent casing errors that don't show up until runtime. As an example of type mismatch, you declare the loctioncounter as integer but use it as a string in the GetLocation method.

There are more but this should get you started in the right direction.

```
Public Class frmMain
Dim yPoint As Integer
Dim LocationDB As String
Dim dtstartdate As Date
Dim dtenddate As Date
Dim LocationName As String
Dim BookSales(17) As Integer
Public Shared locationcounter As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Public Sub Get_Info()
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = Nothing
    Dim command As SqlCommand
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String

    If locationcounter < 18 Then

        dtstartdate = dtpStartDate.Value
        dtenddate = dtpEndDate.Value.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)
        Try
            connetionString = "Data Source=" & LocationDB & ";Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=test"
            sql = "Select * from fGetdata"
            connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
            connection.Open()
            command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 130
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", dtstartdate)
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", dtenddate)
            adapter.Fill(ds)

            For Each FoundRow As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                Select Case FoundRow("CategoryName")
                    Case "TOTAL"
                        Select Case FoundRow("Description")
                            Case "BOOK", "BOOK SALES", "GC"
                                BookSales(i) = BookSales(i) + (FoundRow("netAmt"))
                        End Select

                End Select

            Next

            MsgBox(LocationName & BookSales(i))
            MsgBox(LocationName & BookSales(0))
            MsgBox(LocationName & BookSales(1))


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        Finally
            If connection IsNot Nothing Then
                connection.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub GetLocation()
    Select Case locationcounter
        Case "1"
            LocationName = "Location1"
            LocationDB = "10.0.1.52"
        Case "2"
            LocationName = "Location2"
            LocationDB = "10.0.1.51"
        Case "3"
            LocationName = "Location3"
            LocationDB = "10.0.1.50"

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If you would add ds.clear prior to the SQL Connection I'll accept your answer.  I already dispose the connection after the query is done.  I also do not reference "LocationCounter" as a string.  It's "LocationName" that is a string.  If you clean-up your answer i'll accept it

Comment: @Shmewnix. If you move the DataSet declaration inside the method then it does not need to be cleared because it gets created on each call to Get_Info.  If you don't Dispose the connection in a finally block then it does not get called if there was an exception.  Execution would jump over the Dispose call.  In the GetLocation method the locationcounter is integer but the Case statements are strings.